# Why is Bernie Sanders associated with pudding?

Tags: united-states, bernie-sanders

I have recently heard multiple people make jokes about Bernie Sanders looking for pudding. I did some quick Googling, but only found more references from conservatives on twitter and other media making similar jokes about Bernie Sanders and pudding, but no explanation as to why they are joking about this.

Why are they associating Bernie Sanders with pudding? Is pudding shorthand for something else? Why should people care if he likes pudding?

Comment: It appears to be something Ben Shapiro started. Maybe to poke fun of his age? I dunno. Comedy isn't usually a right-wing pundit's forté.

Comment: Based on Jame's answer, the question should probably be "Explain Ben Shapiro's joke". It doesn't appear that Bernie Sanders is actually associated with pudding beyond that one oddly worded tweet by Ben.

Comment: @blip Short an earlier occurrence, this may be limited to a continued line of derision from Ben Shapiro towards Bernie Sanders, given that Shapiro uses this reference often when discussing Bernie Sanders on his Daily Wire Podcast.

Comment: comments for down votes are appreciated!

Comment: @TBear I think it's just a super narrow question. "Why does Ben Shapiro use this reference?". And the answer seems to be "He thinks its funny for some reason". Just likely not a very meaty question is all.

Comment: @blip note... I didn't ask about Ben Shapiro, nor did I know that it originated from him. I have just heard the reference from several people and thought there might be more to it. If you think a question about how Bernie Sanders is repetitively teased for a bewildering tie to pudding is too narrow, that's fine, but I didn't realize that this was coming from only one real source and others might not as well.

Comment: I'm not accusing you of anything! But as you've found out, it's just not much of a significant event. Just another weird pundit thing.

Comment: Maybe Ben is trying to create an association between Bernie and alleged serial-rapist Bill Cosby?

Comment: because he's a dish best served in a collective pot yet when served in an individualized context is indistinguishable from other units UUUUGUUuuuuuUUUUGHHGHHOOOOOOOOOOOOOHHHHHHHHH!!!!

Comment: It is a reference to someone asking for *dessert* before the meal in a whining and childish manner. The context is that he wants his agenda whether or not it is appropriate or good for the country.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During the CNN debate, on the 8th Feb 2017, Ben Shapiro [tweeted](https://twitter.com/benshapiro/status/829150665809223680?lang=en) "Bernie Sanders WANTS HIS PUDDING AND HE WANTS IT NOW". The "joke" being that Bernie Saunders (aged 75) is old, and so likes soft, slightly sweet food. It's not a subtle joke (and explaining any joke makes it even less funny), pudding doesn't represent anything else.

Ben Shapiro is a journalist who normally adopts a Conservative/right wing position.

Comment: Probably should add "Ben Shapiro is also not a humorist" :)

Comment: Ben Shapiro revisits the reference often in his podcasts when discussing Bernie Sanders, often in the midst of a bad impression.

Comment: okay, so it's just a joke that isn't really that funny? Look at me thinking there was something deeper to this. Guess not!

Comment: Please use chat for general discussion

Comment: In the USA, caretakers often serve pudding in old-age homes as a treat for the older people; I think the joke is moreso that Bernie is old and slightly senile and needs to be contained and put into an old-age home.